# NSTimer gets stuck

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have a app which is using NSTimer to update the UI, in the mean time, the app has lots of logging messages which is using another thread, the problem i have is when the app is logging, the Timer was not fired, until all logging messages are done.
Code:

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(change:) userInfo:imageView repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

[MessageProcessor StartLogging];
```

the change function:

```
- (void)change:(id)sender
{
    p += 0.1;
    UIImageView* view = (UIImageView*)[sender userInfo];
if (p>2) {
    p = 0;
}

// here rotate the image

}
```

After the StartLogging is finished, then the change function will be called by the timer, I wonder to know why, and how to fix that?

Comment: It sounds like `StartLogging` is blocking the current thread so the run loop cannot continue and the timer can never fire. Why do you believe `StartLogging` is using another thread?

Comment: Agreed. BTW, there's no point in having `change` dispatch the update of `test` to the main thread, because you're already on it because you scheduled this timer on the main run loop. But Jonah is right that you probably have something else blocking the main thread and the `MessageProcessor` is the likely culprit on the basis of what's been provided thus far.

Comment: [NSThread isMainThread] shows NO, so i assume the logging is using another thread not the current one.

Comment: Well, plain and simple, if `change:` (which is scheduled on the main run loop and therefore runs on the main thread) is not getting called, it's because something must be blocking the main thread. If not `StartLogging`, then it's something else. As an aside, I don't understand the `view.test = ...` line, because you defined `view` to be a `UIImageView`, which doesn't have a `test` property. And, again, `change` is running on the main runloop, so there's no need to dispatch anything back to the main queue.

Comment: the test is a only an example of the usage, because the propose of the test function is to rotate the image, i am lazy to write them again, sorry, have updated the question

Comment: I have retested with removing the 'dispatch_get_main', still the same, 'change' function was not called.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the case, yes, you guys are right, inside the StartLogging method, i called the main thread to process some data and let it waits unit the data is processed.
Thank you guys.